# Update values which match the same ip php/sql

Tags: php, sql

```
<?

$nick = $_POST['nick'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$regiment = $_POST['regiment'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$servername="localhost";
$username="pp";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username, mygas13)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pp",$conn);

$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


$sql = "SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), `LastPost`) AS 'TimeSinceLast'
        FROM   `userTable`
        WHERE  `ip` = '{$ip}'
        AND    `LastPost` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL  1 DAY)";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $timeSinceLast = date("G\h i\m s\s", strtotime($row['TimeSinceLast']));
$sql="insert into userTable (nick,link,message,regiment,ip,date,submitted) VALUES ('$nick', '$link', '$message', '$regiment', '$ip', '$date', 'Yes') ";

    $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());  

    }
else {
$servername="localhost";
$username="pp";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username, mygas13)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pp",$conn);
$sql="insert into userTable (nick,link,message,regiment,ip,date,submitted) VALUES ('$nick', '$link', '$message', '$regiment', '$ip', '$date', 'No')";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());          

mysql_close($connection);

}
header("Location: thanks.html");
?>
```

This is my input.php. It submits the data but it also checks if multiple submissions come from one ip in 1day period. What i can't do is to update the value submitted for the rest of his/her submissions with yes. I have tried DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but it did not work

Comment: Maybe you got errors? What do they say?

Comment: No i did not get any errors but it did not update them too

Comment: adde     $sql="insert into userTable (nick,link,message,regiment,ip,date,submitted) VALUES ('$nick', '$link', '$message', '$regiment', '$ip', '$date', 'Yes') UPDATE userTable SET submitted='Yes' WHERE ip='$ip'";   but i get this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE userTable SET submitted='Yes' WHERE ip='5.55.67.7'' at line 1

Comment: Solved adding  $sql2="UPDATE userTable SET submitted='yes' WHERE ip='$ip'";     
    $result=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());